# Change the label of the referenced node in teaser view mode

Tags: 7, entities

I'm using Drupal 7 and [Entity Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference)

I have a node, which references another node.

In the teaser view mode, I need to change the label (link) to the referenced entity (to replace the title of this entity by a generic expression of the type "see the referenced node").

Do you have a solution?

Thanks in advance

Comment: So you are wanting the link to actually say "see referenced node" instead of the node title, but the link still go to the actual referenced node?

Comment: Exactly, "see referenced node" instead of the node title, which go to the actual referenced node